# Does Laravel View::composer() risk calling same data twice?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I have a view partial which always needs the same data (say to fill out some nav links) and I provide that data in a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers), do I need to worry about cases where the main page also needs, and loads, this data?
In other words, is it possible to end up duplicating a db query if you're not careful?

Comment: Clarification of question: is a better way of thinking about it to assume that anything loaded by a view composer is *always* available *anywhere* in any page that includes that view or view partial (it is in a boot() method, after all), meaning when I add one, I should then immediately look through my code to check I'm not calling for the same data again elsewhere. ...but perhaps this is obvious now that I think about it.  time for more coding, fewer questions.. :)

Comment: I have just found by experiment that passing a variable to a view partial via a view composer **does not** share the passed variable with subsequent parts of the view, i.e., the variable is not present in the same scope as @include call to the partial that has the composer attached to it.  This complicates things. The question remains: what is the best _workflow_ to add composers; how are they best _used_ (e.g. either initially or as part of a refactor?)

Comment: I tried changing View::composer to View::creator and that still didn't make the variable available in the scope of the view making the @include call to the partial which has the composer/creator registered on it (in AppServiceProvider).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer is yes, you might call for the same data twice.

try adding

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
```

before any database calls, and in the end, before the view is returned, do this:

```
var_dump(DB::getQueryLog());
```

Then you can see if you are calling the same data twice, in the query log.

Comment: For more fine grained debugging, probably wise to recommend installing [Laravel DebugBar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

Answer (score 0):

Summary of how I understand this now:

If a partial needs data **not used elsewhere** in your view, you don't add the call for that to the controller, but to a composer registered on that partial.
All this does for you is get the call out of your controller, to reduce the volume of code there: nothing more. (though if the partial is called by more than one view, it keeps your code DRY).

If a partial needs data **which is also used** on other parts of your page, you should think twice about adding a view composer, as it won't allow you to remove the call for that data, and will just mean you need a duplicate call as will need to pass the variable from your controller in any case (due to scope not being shared, as explained in my comment on the question above).